# Empty Strings as Null is a Bug on Tomcat8?

Tags: java, string, jsf, tomcat8

I'm using Tomcat 8. With the context parameter `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` as `true`, Strings submitted in forms still come as empty strings. On Wildfly this parameter works. Is it a bug of Tomcat 8?

Comment: Yep, see also blog [The empty String madness](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/the-empty-string-madness.html) for a bit of history.

Comment: Thanks, it's works now!